# Laravel: How can I set flash data from a custom provider?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have created a custom user provider to handle authentication. I am able to successfully authenticate and/or handle error responses.

If a user enters an invalid username or password, I am returning a 400 status code along with a message, "Invalid username or password."

I would like to show (or send) this message back to my blade template to let the user know what is wrong.

Currently I am setting a session variable, and that works fine. However, if I refresh the page, the error is still showing.

I would like to use [flash data](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data) to only show the message when the page reloads. Here is what I have currently:

```
// MyUserProvider.php

try {
    // http request...
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    ...
    session()->flash('error', 'Invalid username or password.'); // does not work
    session(['error' => 'Invalid username or password.']); // works
}
```

```
// login.blade.php
...
@if(session()->has('error'))
  {{ session('error') }}
@endif
```

How can I set the flash data from my provider? Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: the user provider doesn't deal with the session, it just handles finding and returning the user from a source ... seems your provider is stepping its bounds (assuming you mean an Auth User Provider)

Comment: What are you trying to do that can’t be achieved with the standard provider?

Comment: @lagbox You are correct; your comment really made me step back at what I have. I am going to continue to update this to reflect what I found. Thank you!

Comment: @Unflux Users for my application are authenticated against another database/service. In short, I have a read-only application that needs to verify a user based on another database.

Comment: @Damon usually what you are doing should be outside the provider and guard, what ever is calling the guard would be what would be dealing with setting any session data like that .... so you would ask the guard to authenticate the user (which uses the provider to try and get the data) and if it can't you then would do what ever you need from there ... hope that helps, but if you have any questions let me know :)

Comment: @lagbox I have a custom guard as well -- to handle this. IDK why it didn't occur to me to handle the "guts" of things there (and not the actual provider). I'll update my post as I go to hopefully help someone else not fall into this trap. :) Thank you for your time!